# Starting mongo then leaving shell without shutting down the server

Tags: mongodb

Hi Guys I start Mongo remotely on Putty SSH and after mongod, it says "listening for ports" but I can't then leave without shutting down the server. how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, look up the [Screen](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/09/27/a-guide-to-gnu-screen/) module. There are other alternatives that do the same thing as well. It basically makes a saved session that you can reattach to later -- I use it extensively to run long tests/services that I can reattach to quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The [Starting and Stopping Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo) documentation article explains several options, one of which is using the `--fork` command line parameter to start `mongod` as a background process. Additionally, you can look into using service controls provided by your operating system (e.g. Windows services, init.d, [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a quick Mongo service script in either Windows or Linux.

You can also press `CTRL`+`Z` which will basically switch it to a background process. This basically gives you back temrinal (or at least does for me).

I also like "Screen". It is quite powerful and easy to navigate so I would personally give that a try.